# In Kotlin, restrict annotation target based on the type of the property

Tags: validation, kotlin, reflection, annotations

In Kotlin, as in Java, we can restrict the annotation to only be used in specific kinds of elements, with the [@Target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html) meta-annotation (ex. `@Target(AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)` so the annotation can only be applied to value parameters).

My use case is that I want to validate properties using reflection (ex. `@MustNotBeEmpty name: String`), and I'd like to restrict the kinds of annotations based on the type of property (ex. `@MustBePositive number: Int` can only be applied to "Int" properties). Comments about the feasibility of reflection-based validation [are welcome as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Is there any way that this can be achieved in compilation time, or will I need to check this in runtime?

Comment: You will only accept “no” if accompanied by proof, won’t you? As to the feasibility: Isn’t that the same approach that is used (quite successfully) by the `javax.validation.*` annotations? Do you want to validate on the setter, or a full object after it has been filled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in the annotation framework that allows this. `kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget` has a wide range of allowed values and can restrict the placement of annotations quite fine-grained (such as ‘only on the getter’), but it’s an closed enum. There is no annotation annotating annotations that takes any type parameter.

All you can do is write a compiler-plugin that performs these checks manually at compile time.